# What is the benefit of a constructor property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, constructor

- What is the benefit of a constructor property ?
- Is it resemble the constructor that in class base in c++ in behavior ?
- What is the intended of the following ?

---

```
obj2.prototype.constructor = obj;
```

**The complete Code:**

```
var obj = function () {
    this.str = "hello world!.";
    obj.prototype.printTxt = function () {
        console.log(this.str);
    };
};

var obj2 = function () {
    this.str = "Good bye";
};

obj2.prototype = new obj;
obj2.prototype.constructor = obj;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `constructor` property is <s>just a convention in JavaScript</s> *(that's no longer true as of ES2015)*; it points to the function that is associated with the prototype on which the `constructor` property exists. That's a bit of a convoluted sentence, so: Assume a function `Foo`. `Foo.prototype.constructor` will be `Foo`. Similarly, assuming `var f = new Foo();`, `f.constructor` will be `Foo`.

<s>It's not actually *used* for anything in the JavaScript standard.</s> *(It is as of ES2015, for things like various `Promise` methods.)* It's just a convention that, unless someone messes it up (which is easy to do), an object will have a `constructor` property it inherits from its prototype that is the function used to create it.

I say it's easy to break that because, well, it is, and people frequently do. Here's an example of breaking it:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype = {
    bar: function() {
    }
};

var f = new Foo();
console.log(f.constructor === Foo); // false
```

---

The code you've quoted is very unusual for JavaScript:

1. Most importantly, it breaks a hugely important rule: You don't change properties on the prototype from within the constructor (except in **very** edge-case scenarios). (Although in this particular case, it does so in a harmless but pointless way.)
2. It breaks a fundamental naming rule in JavaScript: That constructor functions start with a capital letter (`Obj`, not `obj`).
3. And it shows an all-too-common, but fundamentally broken, pattern for setting up inheritance hierarchies.

So on the whole, I would probably not use whatever resource it was that you got that code from.

FWIW, here's a corrected version of that code:

```
function Base() {
    this.str = "hello world!.";
}
Base.prototype.printTxt = function () {
    console.log(this.str);
};

function Derived() {
    this.str = "Good bye";
}

Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived;
```

`Object.create` was defined by ECMAScript5. This single-argument version of it can be shimmed for older engines (the multi-argument version of it cannot be), like this:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(proto) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            throw "The multi-argument version of Object.create cannot be shimmed.";
        }

        function ctor() { }
        ctor.prototype = proto;

        return new ctor();
    };
}
```